# Gnuplot, heat-map, label certain point

Tags: label, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a heat map and the plot is done. Though I need to label certain points with some name tags. I used the command label but it is not working. I checked but I didn't get any solution that worked. Thanks in advance.

I am adding the basic script that I am using to generate.

```
set terminal postscript portrait enhanced color size 16cm,12cm
set output "pdiff.pdf"
set style data lines
set pm3d


set xlabel "Baseline  in km" 
set ylabel "Energy  in GeV"

set view map scale 1
unset surf
set cbrange [-0.04:0.05]
set xrange [200:1500]
set yrange [0.2:5]
set xtics 100,200,1500
set ytics 0,0.5,5

set label "DUNE" at 1300,2.521 point pt 28 ps 1   
set label "NOvA" at 812,1.574 point pt 22 ps 1
set label "KD" at 1100,2.133 point pt 20 ps 1
set pm3d interpolate 5,7
set palette defined ( 0 0.05 0.05 0.2, 0.1 0 0 1, 0.25 0.7 0.85 0.9,\
     0.4 0 0.75 0, 0.5 1 1 0, 0.7 1 0 0, 0.9 0.6 0.6 0.6,\
     1 0.95 0.95 0.95 )
splot "pdiff.txt" using 1:2:3 notitle with labels
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here.

1. You will need to draw the pm3d surface separately from the labels
2. "splot with labels" requires 4 columns of information: x, y, z, label

Assuming that the columns in your data file are in fact x, y, z, label
try:

```
splot "pdiff.txt" using 1:2:3 with pm3d, \
      "pdiff.txt" using 1:2:3:4 with labels
```

You should number the labels not taken from the file so that you can refer to them individually. Also, since you use the 3D command `splot` you should give x,y,and z coordinates to the labels. To move individual labels to the front (drawn after everything else), add the keyword `front`, as in

```
set label 1 "DUNE" at 1300, 2.521, 0.0 point pt 28 ps 1
set label 1 front
set label 2 "NOvA" at 812, 1.574, 0.0 point pt 22 ps 1
set label 2 front
```

Comment: Okay @Ethan thanks I tried, but it's still not working!

Comment: Please suggest something else! I don't have four columns, because the labels that I want to add at are mostly not in the data file.

Comment: It is impossible to diagnosis what is going wrong when the only description is "not working".  Does it draw a pm3d surface?  Does it place labels anywhere?  If the labels are not in the file, why was the command shown in your original question `splot "pdiff.txt" with labels`?  Are there error messages?

Comment: I actually tried using it that way, but it didn't work. In the script as you can see I have added set  label "DUNE" at ......, I want that to be added, This is coming but it is behind this surface of heat map so it is not visible.

Comment: See amended answer